# 100% div containers with margin + fixed navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a webpage with:

- a fixed navigation panel on the left hand screen
- a div container on the right hand that hosts content in smaller div containers (which have 100% width + margin)

The problem is I can not get what I want without compromising on the navigation or size of the content div containers.

What I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/u5j7ayud/

I hope some of what I said made sense, if not look at the illustrations below

Incorrect (current state):

```
 ___________
| ___|_____ |
||___|_____||
| ___|_____ |
||___|_____||
|____|______|
```

Correct (desired state):

```
 ____________
|    | _____ |
|    ||_____||
|    | _____ |
|    ||_____||
|____|_______|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your layout...

The `position: fixed` of your nav is a bad idea. It takes the element out of the flow of the page, and your `float: left` becomes useless.

It's better to let the content fill the screen automatically through inline positioning techniques, such as css tables. I'd recomend you to turn your `nav` and `content` div into `display: table-cell` elements.

Then, setting the `width: 200px` on the nav would make the content div to fill the remaining space:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5j7ayud/1/)

```
body{
    padding:0; margin:0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
   display: table-cell;
   background: black;
   overflow: auto;
}

#box{
   background: red;
   min-height: 200px;
   margin: 10px
}

.nav {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background:blue;
    text-align:right;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I can use the .nav container as a wrapper for a fixed navigation

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2tybnho2/1/

```
.nav  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.contents {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

there is a very simple way, now the trick is getting scrolling to work right in the contents. Basically what it does it sets the corners to a specified area of the screen and makes them not move out of that position.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your ***#content*** element ***fixed*** panel's width by margin.

```
#content {
   background: black;
   overflow: auto;
   width:100%;
   margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want, this ends up making the page too large that I have to scroll through the page horizontally

Comment: To avoid this problem you should convert your fixed panel's width and #content margin px into % to make it responsive and there won't be horizontal scroll.